# We are twins - Who are we?

Tags: riddle

> We are twins, living side by side.
>
> Most of the time, we cannot see each other.
>
> Occasionally, we can see each other with the help of a friend.

Who are we?

Comment: @AJ I was just about to flag it. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir You can still flag it. A +1 will be added to my comment.

Comment: @AJ I did that already. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

> eyes

Because

> They live side by side.They cant see each other, but with the help of mirror they can.

Answer (score 2):

> Most probably the answer is Eyes